# Stop deleting user from UITable if user selects the cancel button from UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a table with some names loaded from a plist and what I'm trying to do is basically remove the one selected by the user and everything is working fine, but what I'm trying to do that I cannot figure out is basically give the user the option of cancel or continue with the deletion using a UIAlertView.

This is what I have that obviously doesn't work and it deletes the user regardless of what button was touched.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // This is fine since here I'm only notifying the user that guest cannot be deleted
    UITableViewCell *celectedRow = [self.tableScores cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *removeUserWithKey = celectedRow.textLabel.text;

    if ([removeUserWithKey isEqual: @"Guest"])
    {
        // don't remove anything and show message
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information!"
                                                        message:@"The user 'Guest' cannot be removed."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else
    {
        // the problem I have is here, how can I stop deleting and saving  
        // if user selects the cancel button
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information!"
                                                        message:@"The user 'Guest' cannot be removed."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [alert show];

        //IF USER NAME IS OTHER THAN GUEST REMOVE IT
        // remove selected row from table
        [arrayRecords removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // remove selected user from dictionary
        [dictionaryCopyOfRecordsFromPlist removeObjectForKey:removeUserWithKey];

        // write dictionary to plist after removing items
        [self.pListReader writeToPlist:@"studentsRecords.plist" withDictionary:dictionaryCopyOfRecordsFromPlist];

        // reload items in table to reflect any changes made
        [self.tableScores reloadData];
    }
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Continue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Continue.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
    {
       NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    }
}
```

Again, this code works fine if I wouldn't want to give the user the option of cancelling the deletion.

How can I structure my code in a way that I can cancel the deleting process if user selects the cancel button?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you remove the object from the array only when the user presses  continue button. Move the code for removal of guest to alert view delegate

Tag the alert view with the row number.

```
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information!"
                                                    message:@"The user 'Guest' cannot be removed."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    alert.tag = indexPath.row;
    [alert show];
```

Remove the record in Alert view delegate.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

  if([title isEqualToString:@"Continue"])
  {
    NSLog(@"Continue.");

    //Remove the corresponding row.
    [arrayRecords removeObjectAtIndex:alertView.tag];

    // remove selected user from dictionary
    [dictionaryCopyOfRecordsFromPlist removeObjectForKey:removeUserWithKey];

    // write dictionary to plist after removing items
    [self.pListReader writeToPlist:@"studentsRecords.plist" withDictionary:dictionaryCopyOfRecordsFromPlist];

    // reload items in table to reflect any changes made
    [self.tableScores reloadData];
}
  else if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
  {
     NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     //Do Nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked fine, I just don't fully understand how `[arrayRecords removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` got replaced by `[arrayRecords removeObjectAtIndex:alertView.tag];` how is alertView.tag getting the indexPath.row? Sorry if I don't see the obvious.

Comment: I had set it here, alert.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: Sorry but I just dont get the relation between the two, how does alertView.tag know about the index of the uitable? From apple docs - tag:
An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

Comment: I had set that in the alert view code.See the first code block, second line. UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information!"
                                                    message:@"The user 'Guest' cannot be removed."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    alert.tag = indexPath.row;
    [alert show];

Comment: Oh I see, I apologize for not seeing that. The funny thing is that in  my code I don't have `alert.tag = indexPath.row;` and it's working fine, that's weird, that's why I was confused. I will add that piece of code but first I will try to play around without it to see how this is working without it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I said it was working fine without `alert.tag = indexPath.row;` but I didn't notice that it was always deleting the first item (index 0) in the array. Thanks a lot  `Naveen Prasad R`  for your help.